# Python: How to calculate the mean heart rate during a specific time frame of my data?

Tags: python, mean, heartrate

I am trying to measure the changes in heart rate throughout the continuous resting and exercise periods of my experiment. How can I calculate the mean heart rate of just the resting period, from approximately 0 to 120 seconds?

[For reference, this is the filtered heart rate vs time graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnRlY.png)

To supply some background, I started from an ECG analog signal, found the R-wave peaks and calculated the RR interval. Using the RR interval, I was able to calculate heart rate. I filtered out the outliers of the raw heart rate plot, and thus came up with the graph that I linked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add some code about what you have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take you have a list of values behind that graph?

```
import numpy
numpy.mean([1,2,3])

import statistics
statistics.mean([1,2,3])
```

Beware that statistics is **much** slower than numpy - albeit fractionally more accurate (talking 12th decimal point more accurate or something like that!).

If you have adjacent timeframes (as you must for plotting your x-values), then you can index your window start and end via (you define the <start_time> and <end_time>):

```
iStart = timeList.index(<start_time>)
iEnd = timeList.index(<end_time>)
```

and do your mean across that

```
meanRate = numpy.mean(rateList[iStart:iEnd])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!